# Domain error in Julia to compute caputo fractional derivative with Quadgk

Tags: julia

I'm trying to evaluate caputo derivative using Quadgk. It works unless when `t=3` it gives me Domain error. With Mathematica I got the value `-3.11522`

```
using QuadGK, ForwardDiff, SpecialFunctions
f(t)=t^2*sin(t);
g= t-> ForwardDiff.derivative(t->f(t) , t)
F(t) = x-> g(x)/(gamma(1/2)* √(t-x))
caputo(t) = quadgk(F(t), 0, t)[1]
caputo(3)
```

This is the error

```
DomainError with 2.9999999999999787: integrand produced Inf in the interval (2.9999999999999574, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add rtol to quadGK

```
using QuadGK, ForwardDiff, SpecialFunctions
f(t)=t^2*sin(t);
g= t-> ForwardDiff.derivative(t->f(t) , t)
F(t) = x-> g(x)/(gamma(1/2)* √(t-x))
caputo(t) = quadgk(F(t), 0, t, rtol=10^-6)[1]
caputo(3)
```

Now it returns

```
-3.1152157952144024
```

You can also use FractionalCalculus.jl

```
using FractionalCalculus

fracdiff(x->x^2*sin(x),0.5,3,10^-5,CaputoDiethelm())
```